# SQL loop to add dates to table not working

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, while-loop

I have a WHILE loop that should loop 30 times but for some reason it only seems to loop 15 times.

SQL:

```
DECLARE @dateInsert date
DECLARE @dateLoopTo date
DECLARE @cnt INT = 0;
SET @dateInsert='2016-01-01'
SET @dateLoopTo='2016-01-31'

WHILE @cnt <=  DATEDIFF (d, @dateInsert , @dateLoopTo )
BEGIN
print CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),@dateInsert) + ' '+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(2),@cnt)
SET @dateInsert = DATEADD(d, 1,@dateInsert)
SET @cnt = @cnt + 1;
END
```

Results:

```
2016-01-01 0,
2016-01-02 1,
2016-01-03 2,
2016-01-04 3,
2016-01-05 4,
2016-01-06 5,
2016-01-07 6,
2016-01-08 7,
2016-01-09 8,
2016-01-10 9,
2016-01-11 10,
2016-01-12 11,
2016-01-13 12,
2016-01-14 13,
2016-01-15 14,
```

When I try changing DATEDIFF (d, @dateInsert , @dateLoopTo ) to 30 the SQL seems to work.

```
WHILE @cnt <= 30-- DATEDIFF (d, @dateInsert , @dateLoopTo )
```

Is there are reason the DATEDIFF (d, @dateInsert , @dateLoopTo ) which returns 30 does not work?

Comment: Since you change `dateInsert` in the loop, I can't see how `DATEDIFF (d, @dateInsert , @dateLoopTo )` would still return 30 after the first iteration.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You increment `cnt` and decrement `DATEDIFF`(incrementing `@dateInsert` inside loop causes decrementing difference) the same time:

```
First iteration:  cnt = 0; DATEDIFF(d, @dateInsert , @dateLoopTo ) = 30
Second iteration: cnt = 1; DATEDIFF = 29
Third iteration:  cnt = 2; DATEDIFF = 28

..
15th iteration:   cnt = 15; DATEDIFF = 15
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/413397?opt.textResults=true)**</kbd>

One way to avoid it is to use fixed value:

```
WHILE @cnt <= 30
```

or declare new variable:

```
DECLARE @steps INT = DATEDIFF (d, @dateInsert , @dateLoopTo );

WHILE @cnt <= steps
...
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo2`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/413399)**</kbd>

Answer (score 6):

At each step through the loop, you are incrementing *both* `cnt` and `@DateInsert`.  Hence, you are walking through by 2s.

How about writing the code more clearly as:

```
WHILE @cnt <= 30
```

Answer (score 2):

```
DECLARE @dateInsert date
DECLARE @dateLoopTo date
```

declare a count variable and use it in while condition

```
DECLARE @cnt INT = 0;
SET @dateInsert='2016-01-01'
SET @dateLoopTo='2016-01-31'
DECLARE @Count INT =DATEDIFF (d, @dateInsert , @dateLoopTo )
WHILE @cnt <=  @Count
BEGIN
print CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),@dateInsert) + ' '+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(2),@cnt)
SET @dateInsert = DATEADD(d, 1,@dateInsert)
SET @cnt = @cnt + 1;
END
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using a set-based approach which is what I'd recommend over loops wherever possible. To list all dates between 2 dates you can do:

```
DECLARE @dateInsert date
DECLARE @dateLoopTo date
SET @dateInsert='2016-01-01'
SET @dateLoopTo='2016-01-31'

SELECT DATEADD(dd, Number, @dateInsert)
FROM
(
    SELECT TOP (DATEDIFF(dd, @dateInsert, @dateLoopTo)) 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY o.object_id) - 1 AS Number
    FROM sys.objects o
        CROSS JOIN sys.objects o2
) x
```

If this is common activity, I'd recommend creating a Numbers table in the database (single column, and populate it once with numbers from 1 to x, where x=roughly how high you will need numbers to go plus a bit extra). And, again depending on use cases/scenarios, you can also create a "Dates" table and prepopulate that - these basically remove the need to calculate date ranges each time.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer (because an answer already has provided by `@Gordon Linoff`), but a way to achieve what you need without using `WHILE loop`, with using more native query. This variant is similar with `@AdaTheDev` answer, but without using sys tables (may be you have restriction for using them)

here variant using *recursive cte*

```
DECLARE @dateInsert date = '2016-01-01'
;
WITH CTE AS 
          (
            SELECT @dateInsert as Dt, n = 1
             UNION ALL
             SELECT DATEADD(day,n,@dateInsert), n = n + 1
             FROM CTE
             WHERE DATEADD(day,n,@dateInsert) <= EOMONTH(@dateInsert)
           )

SELECT * FROM CTE
```

please note, that `EOMONTH()` function is available since 2012 version
also, please note, that if you using `recursive cte` then server will use default iteration equal to 100, if you need more than 100 then you need additional `option (Maxrecursion *here number*)`

so, for example, query below will give you 365 day's sequence:

```
DECLARE @dateInsert date = '2016-01-01'

;WITH CTE AS 
              (
                 SELECT @dateInsert as Dt, n = 1
                 UNION ALL
                 SELECT DATEADD(day,n,@dateInsert) as Dt, n = n + 1
                 FROM CTE
                 WHERE n <=365
               )

    SELECT * FROM CTE

    OPTION(MAXRECURSION 365)
```

Comment: Be careful here. You are using a cte to count which looks like it is set based but it is really the same thing as a loop cleverly hidden. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/74118/